# Reading the HTML Form data

Tags: javascript, html, json

my html form is sending data to the server as :

```
{ r1: [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  r2: [ 'Top', 'Greg', 'Andy' ],
  r3: [ 'validuser', 'invaliduser', 'validuser' ] }
```

I know that this is a group infpormation for 3 sets (3 Arrays)

```
1,Top,Validuser
2, greg, invaliduser
3, Andy , valid user
```

How can I make/Read to have them as an array as mentioned?

The form is sending like that because it is based on a java script template where in I have the template of the form :

```
   <td>   <input type="text" name="r1" id="mytext" size="9" value=${usernumber} /> </td>
```

Comment: Sorry. I could't get you. did you mean JSON.parse('data')?;

Comment: First I want to read them as Arrays.

Comment: How, _exactly,_ is the data sent to the server?

Comment: Its send exactly as I mentioned in the question. I use Javascript on my server for Node. when I do console.log I get that line

Comment: And your server side language is ?

Comment: javascript and the way I read the value on the server as mentioned

Comment: In javascript you can use JSON.parse('{...}');

Comment: yes but the data I am getting from form is not in JSON. please let me know if I am not clear ..

Comment: this seems to be the JSON response , try to parse it as json

Comment: it looks json. it is not. it is the output of the form data send to the server.please look at the data and question

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you're using POST, you'd read the value like this:

$var_array[1]=$_POST["mytext"];

Comment: my form is having minimum 30 entries so dont want to use $_. that my server is reading the data as mentioines trying to make sure of that in Javascript. Btn I use Javascript for my server (node)